# Same URL Response.Redirect in Kentico schedule task

Tags: asp.net, instagram-api, kentico

I have created a schedule job in Kentico 9 to call and get the instagram images ,
In the job

```
string returnUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", RequestContext.CurrentScheme, RequestContext.FullDomain, "/cmspages/sqd/instagramfeed.aspx").ToLower();
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(returnUrl));
try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //We know its going to fail but that dosent matter!!
}
```

so this will goes to the /cmspages/sqd/instagramfeed.aspx,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EventLogProvider.LogInformation("Start Instagramfeed" , "1"); 

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"]) && !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            code = Request["code"].ToString();
            ProcessAndDownloadInstagramImages();

            EventLogProvider.LogInformation("End Instagramfeed", "2");     
        }
        else
        {
            string returnUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, "/cmspages/sqd/instagramfeed.aspx").ToLower();
            try
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(ResHelper.GetString("SQD.Instagram.OauthUrl", "en-AU"), ResHelper.GetString("SQD.Instagram.ClientId", "en-AU").ToString(), returnUrl));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                //Do nothing
            }       
        }
    }
```

So here it will agin redirecting to the same url with the code parameter,

If I run directly the /cmspages/sqd/instagramfeed.aspx url in the browser it works without any issue but when I try with a job Response.Redirect in page load will fail.

Comment: Since you're running in a scheduled task I suspect your RequestContext won't contain valid parameters. This static class expects to be used in the context of an HTTP request. Have you tried hard-coding the returnUrl  variable in your first code block to eliminate that concern?

Comment: @getsetcode is right. Maybe you could share the exception you're getting...

Answer (score 0):

Just read about [HttpResponse.Redirect Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing false for the endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the End method.

So I think you should use:

```
Response.Redirect("/url", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Maybe it'll help you

Or you should check what URL is in here:

```
string.Format(ResHelper.GetString("SQD.Instagram.OauthUrl", "en-AU"), ResHelper.GetString("SQD.Instagram.ClientId", "en-AU").ToString(), returnUrl)
```